# Is there a pathlib equivalent to os.path.basename under Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pathlib

When running Python 3.9.5 on Windows 10:

- `Path("c:/temp/one/two/").name == "two"`
- `PurePath("c:/temp/one/two/").name == "two"`
- `PureWindowsPath("c:/temp/one/two/").name == "two"`

while

- `os.path.basename("c:/temp/one/two/").name == ""`

Comment: `os.path.basename(os.path.realpath("C:/temp/one/two/"))` or `os.path.basename(os.path.normpath("C:/temp/one/two/"))`?

Comment: I'm sorry, my question wasn't entirely clear.  I'm looking for a `pathlib` equivalent that will return the same thing that `os.path.basename("c:/temp/one/two/")` returns, i.e. the empty string ""

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) `os.path.basename` simply uses `.split()`.  It therefore is a fairly rudimentary implementation.  (The docs even explicitly mention to not expect the same result as for the Unix "basename" program.)

In `pathlib`, the `Path`, `PurePath` or `PureWindowsPath` objects are more sophisticated.  They can represent a file, a directory, or something else.  The object does not make any assumptions about what it is representing until you call its methods (e.g. `.is_file()`).  Therefore `Path("c:/temp/one/two/").name` will return `two`, because `two` is merely a sub-directory in `one` (the `Path` object doesn't care whether it is a file or directory).

To get parity with `os.path.basename`, you can do something like

```
p = Path("c:/temp/one/two/")
("" if p.is_dir() else p.name) == ""
```

Or, if you want a one-liner (on Python 3.9+):

```
("" if (p := Path("c:/temp/one/two/")).is_dir() else p.name) == ""
```

By the way, `os.path.basename` does accept a `Path` object as a parameter.  *However*, the behaviour is different:

```
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.28.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import os

In [2]: from pathlib import Path

In [3]: os.path.basename('c:/one/two/three/')
Out[3]: ''

In [4]: os.path.basename(Path('c:/one/two/three/'))
Out[4]: 'three'
```